# Bad Mime with PHP Mail?

Tags: php, html, email

I've migrated a site from one server to another. On the old server the contact page works fine, on the new one it doesn't.  I've contacted support and they sent me the log which doesn't reveal anything asides form an unrelated undeclared variable.  I contact again and was able to find out that another error was being generated :

```
policy-violation_found_in_sent_message_"Contact_Form"

Policy:Bad_MIME:RC:1
```

Can anyone help please?

The bulk of the code is below, I can't see the problem, on one server it works fine, on another it doesn't.

Thanks for any help.

```
   if(isset($_POST['name'])){    //may have to change to see if a field was set instead


    $myEmail       = 'me@me.com'; //Email address where queries get sent.
    //errors already defined in init
    $name          = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
    $email         = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));

    $subject = "Contact Form";

    $headers = "From: " .$email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .$email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    //body of message
    $message1 = '<html><body>';
    $message1 .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message1 .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$name. "</td></tr>";
    $message1 .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" .$email. "</td></tr>";
    $message1 .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" .$message. "</td></tr>";
    $message1 .= "</table>";
    $message1 .= "</body></html>";

if (mail($myEmail, $subject, $message1, $headers)) {

 //Whoop!
    } else {
        echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
    }
}
```

I've removed fields and some validation etc but thats the bulk of it.

Comment: It beats me why so many people spend so much time trying to get php's `mail()` function to work nicely with custom headers and multi-part messages. It's just a complete nightmare, and really *really* difficult to make it secure (trust me, your code would be hacked in seconds to send spam). Why do people keep writing all this code when classes like phpMailer and Swiftmailer exist already, are completely free, and do all this work for you? Job done -- download phpMailer, and replace all that code with a few simple lines.

Comment: @Spudley because they don't know any better. And how would they, since [manual page](http://fi1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) says nothing about the fact that it is crap and should really be deprecated.

Comment: @eis: yes, that was a rant; sorry about that  :) But the point stands: If you come to SO looking for help with PHP mail, the first thing you should do is search for previous similar questions, and if you do that, you'll find hundreds of answers saying to use phpMailer or Swiftmailer instead. It's not like the information is hard to find.

Comment: @Spudley - my main gripe with changing to swiftmailer etc is that I spent so much time getting this to work.  If I can make it work then I'm happy.  I;ve validtion and ither stuff going on to try and avoid spam as much as possible.  Just a preference and....as eis said, when I started writing it, I didn't know any better.

Comment: @SteveGreen - well, you may get it working, but it's not going to be secure as things stand; `strip_tags()` is completely useless for sanitising an email address. You need to prevent mail header injection, which is an entirely different problem. The short answer is that you need to watch out for sneaky `\n` characters in your input, but that's not the whole story; it's actually quite hard to write fully secure mail when you're creating the headers manually. This is the main reason to use a decent library. The fact that they make your code much easier to write and maintain is a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Policy:Bad_MIME:RC:1` is an error message of [qmail_scanner](http://qmail-scanner.sourceforge.net/) set up by your hosting provider. It's not directly related to PHP.

From its [source code](http://svn.deeproot.in/deepofix/deepofix/tags/deepOfix-Install-CD-3.2/packages/qmail-scanner/src/qmail-scanner-queue.pl):

```
  if (!$quarantine_event && $illegal_mime && $headers{'mime-version'} && $BAD_MIME_CHECKS) {
    $destring="problem";
    $quarantine_description="Disallowed  characters found in MIME headers" if (!$quarantine_description);
    $quarantine_event="Policy:Bad_MIME";
    $description .= "\n---perlscanner results ---\n$destring '$quarantine_description'\n found in message";
  }
```

So basically it doesn't like some characters in your MIME headers.

My guess is that it doesn't like the `\r` character, since you seem to have those, and it does this check

```
  if ($BAD_MIME_CHECKS && !$IGNORE_EOL_CHECK && /\r|\0/) {
    $illegal_mime=1;
    &debug("w_c: found CRL/NULL in header - invalid if this is a MIME message");
    &minidebug("w_c: found CRL/NULL in header - invalid if this is a MIME message");
  }
```

so using just `\n` instead of `\r\n` might resolve the problem.

If it doesn't, you could ask your hosting provider to provide at least the debug messages so you would be able to debug what's wrong.

Or give up debugging and use another mail server/mail protocol/sending class.

---

Addition: It seems it's actually even [documented](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#cr) that qmail doesn't accept `\r\n`, only `\n`. PHP Manual also [states that](https://www.php.net/function.mail)

> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail
> transfer agents (most notably qmail) replace LF by CRLF
> automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This
> should be a last resort, as it does not comply with RFC 2822.

Comment: thanks for the advice - i removed the mime type and it works, bad idea?

Comment: You were right, thanks!  REmoving the \r solved it perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Np, glad it worked. It seems it's actually [documented](http://fi2.php.net/function.mail#40204) that qmail doesn't accept `\r\n`, only `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

**Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), your life will be easier.**

Use example :

```
require_once('swift/lib/swift_required.php');

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setFrom(array($from))
    ->setTo(array($to))
    ->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get7BitEncoding())
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
    ->addPart(strip_tags($body), 'text/plain')
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filename))
;
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: thanks for the advice - i removed the mime type and it works, bad idea?